# How to efficiently iterate through a base-2 vector

Tags: c, loops, vector, binary

I need to write a program that iterates through all possible combinations for a base-2 (binary) vector. If the size of this vector is 3 you can do this with three nested loops, like this:

```
bool array[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            array[0] = i;
            array[1] = j;
            array[2] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that in my application, the array size is variable and can basically be any number. If I'm looking to find all values of a 12-bit vector, I don't want to write 12 nested loops and so it is not maintainable to use the code above. Instead I have come up with the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE    12

int main(void)
{
    bool array[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) array[i] = 1;
    int max_num = pow(2, SIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < max_num; i++)
    {
        if(array[0] == 0) array[0]++;
        else
        {
            array[0] = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if(array[j] == 1) array[j] = 0;
                else
                {
                    array[j] = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", array[j]);
            if(j != SIZE - 1) printf(", ");
            else printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This still seems as a lot of code to me for such a relatively simple thing. My question is: **is there a more efficient way to do this?**

Comment: Increment an unsigned number of 12 bits

Comment: With a lot of caution, you should study how does recursive function works

Comment: Short version: `v++`

Comment: Those are good ideas, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with the array is effectively incrementing (adding one) to the number represented by the array.
Let's leave the incrementing to the compiler and use bits from the integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE    12

int main(void)
{
    bool array[SIZE];
    int max_num = 1 << SIZE;

    for(int i = 0; i < max_num; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            array[j] = (i >> j) & 1;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", array[j]);
            if(j != SIZE - 1) printf(", ");
            else printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LPs I don't know the requirements, but at least the output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, it is essentially incrementing a binary number. However, in keeping with the spirit of the original code, I decided not to "cheat" by using native addition/increment operators to increment the vector, and came up with the following:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool first(size_t size, bool array[size])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    return i > 0;
}

bool next(size_t size, bool array[size])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size && array[i]; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    if (i < size)
    {
        array[i] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { SIZE = 12 };
    bool array[SIZE];
    bool going;

    for (going = first(SIZE, array); going; going = next(SIZE, array))
    {
        size_t i;

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
        {
            printf("%d, ", array[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It could be adapted to work in other bases easily:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool first(size_t size, unsigned int array[size])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    return i > 0;
}

bool next(size_t size, unsigned int array[size], unsigned int base)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size && array[i] == base - 1; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    if (i < size)
    {
        array[i]++;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { SIZE = 5 };
    enum { BASE = 3 };
    unsigned int array[SIZE];
    bool going;

    for (going = first(SIZE, array); going; going = next(SIZE, array, BASE))
    {
        size_t i;

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
        {
            printf("%u, ", array[i]);
        }
        printf("%u\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```